# UTF-8 response encoding with appengine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, encoding, utf-8

I need to set the character encoding of the HTTP response to UTF-8.

```
JsonObject jsonObject;

resp.setContentType("application/json; charset=UTF-8");
//resp.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
out.print(jsonObject.toString());
```

I have try to set encoding on content type, using the specific response method and with system property on `appengine-web.xml`

```
<property name="file.encoding" value="UTF-8" />
<property name="DEFAULT_ENCODING" value="UTF-8" />
```

Every method work fine in in local, but when i deploying my application to App Engine the character encoding goes wrong, and the JSON response String 
displayed in my browser is not UTF-8. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

If encoding error is in `PrintWriter` you can try to write to response not string, but array of characters, as:

```
out.print(jsonObject.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

Otherwise try another library to generate json, such as GSON.

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
out.print(gson.toJson(Your_Object));
```